# Reallocation of argv

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

I was looking at the code for the GNU coreutils package, specifically [the program 'yes'](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/yes.c), when I saw this block of code in the `main` function (line 78):

```
if (argc <= optind)
{
  optind = argc;
  argv[argc++] = bad_cast ("y");
}
```

How can the array `argv` be expanded this way? Obviously, just taking any code snippet out of context is a really bad idea, so I looked to see if `argv` is modified at all beforehand, and it doesn't seem to be except in a call to `initialize_main (&argc, &argv)`, which doesn't seem like it takes an argument for a "new size" or anything like that (but in C, like any language, things aren't always what they seem to be).

I decided to write a simple program to test if I could call `realloc()` on `argv`

```
char** new_argv = realloc(argv, ++argc * sizeof*argv);
```

And it worked (with VS2013 on Windows 10). It returned a pointer to the allocated memory. Of course, that doesn't actually mean *anything* if it's undefined behavior.

So, long story short, my question is, how is `argv` allocated? Is it actually safe to realloc `argv`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's unspecified thus UB; you'd better malloc + memcpy. Consider that coreutils is written for a specific platform, where some behaviors are known.

Comment: `argv` is an array of pointers to `char` (owned by the program), the last one, i.e. `argv[argc]` is supposed to be a null pointer, so it can be made to point to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
argv[argc++] = bad_cast ("y");
```

This does not expand the `argv` array. It merely assigns a value to `argv[argc]` and then increments `argc`. This does break the initial guarantee that `argv[argc] == NULL`, but as long as the code doesn't rely on that it's valid.

The standard guarantees that:

> The parameters **`argc`** and **`argv`** and the strings pointed to by the argv
>   array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored
>   values between program startup and program termination.

It does not explicitly guarantee that the `char*` pointers in the array that `argv` points to are modifiable, but it's a reasonable assumption that they are. (Strictly speaking `argv` points to the first element of the array, not to the array itself, but that sentence was long enough already.)

```
char** new_argv = realloc(argv, ++argc * sizeof*argv);
```

This has undefined behavior. The first argument to `realloc` must be either a null pointer or a pointer to memory allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, or equivalent. The memory pointed to by `argv` is allocated in some unspecified manner before `main` is entered. You can make a copy of the array, but you can't legally deallocate it, which is part of what `realloc` does. If the `realloc` call behaved "correctly" for you, you were just unlucky. (If you'd been *lucky*, your program would have crashed, which would have told you that there's a problem.)

Comment: I like this answer better because it's more in-depth and more directly answers my question.

Comment: Excellent answer! Especially UB and unlucky / lucky part.

Answer (score 5):

First, `argv[argc]` is defined to be `NULL`.

Second, `argc++` increments `argc` but returns its old value.

Thus, `argv[argc++] = ...` doesn't invoke undefined behaviour; it simply assigns a new value to a previously `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Is `argv[argc]` it guaranteed to be `NULL`?

Comment: @ThePcLuddite it is, From the Standard 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup - 2 `argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.`